# Xamarin Google SignIn for Android - Refresh and Access Tokens

Tags: android, xamarin, token, google-signin

Using VisualStudio, I recently successfully implemented client-flow authentication for my `Xamarin.Forms` app via the `Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn NuGet` package. This sign-in is then used to allow the app access to our server API components via Azure Mobile Services `MobileServicesClient`.

It hinges on the ability to pass to Azure the `access_token`, `refresh_token`, and `id_token` from the Google IDP API - all 3 of which are available nicely after a sign in as `SignIn.SharedInstance.CurrentUser.Authentication.AccessToken`, `SignIn.SharedInstance.CurrentUser.Authentication.RefreshToken` and `SignIn.SharedInstance.CurrentUser.Authentication.IdToken`.

I am now trying to implement similar behavior in the Android version of our `Xamarin.Forms` app using the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth NuGet` package. 
However, although I think I have the basics in place for getting a successful authentication with Google, I cannot see how to retrieve the tokens I need from the result.

The google documentation talks about enabling retrieval of the `IDToken` and `ServerAuthCode` via setting up the `GoogleSignInOptions` object before building the APIClient, but not how to get the `refresh_` or `access_token` from google? It seems to want to lay this responsibility onto our sever API. That is not how our iOS app works. Anyone successfully done this in an app using this NuGet package API? Does the Xamarin Android Google SignIn API even support what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, try something like the following (disregarding where we see App.PostLoginAction - that is specific to my app, although certainly you can take a similar approach and implement an action at the App level as I have done to catch the results).

```
public class GoogleLoginService : Java.Lang.Object, GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener
{
    public static GoogleApiClient GoogleApiClient { get; set; }
    public static GoogleLoginService Instance { get; private set; }

    public GoogleLoginService()
    {
        Instance = this;
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
            .RequestIdToken("YourAppsWebClientId") //note this is the WEB client id, NOT the android app client id
            .RequestEmail()
            .Build();

        GoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity) //note you need to install the plugin king's (James Montemagno) Plugin.CurrentActivity nuget for this
            .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .AddApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .AddScope(new Scope(Scopes.Email))
            .AddScope(new Scope(Scopes.Profile))
            .Build();
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInIntent(GoogleApiClient);
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.StartActivityForResult(signInIntent, 1);
        GoogleApiClient.Connect();
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        GoogleApiClient.Disconnect();
    }

    public void OnAuthCompleted(GoogleSignInResult result)
    {
        if (result.IsSuccess)
        {               
            Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> {
                //note result.SignInAccount.IdToken is NOT the access token, so we need this:
                var accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.GetToken(Android.App.Application.Context, result.SignInAccount.Account, $"oauth2:{Scopes.Email} {Scopes.Profile}");
                App.PostLoginAction(SocialProvider.Google, accessToken , "Success!");
            });

            //to get user profile directly, without having to make separate call using the access token:
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.SignInAccount; //contains stuff like name, email, pic url, gender
        }
        else
        {
            App.PostLoginAction(SocialProvider.Google, null, "An error occurred.");
        }
    }

    public void OnConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    {

    }

    public void OnConnectionSuspended(int cause)
    {
        App.PostLoginAction(SocialProvider.Google, null, "Canceled!");
    }

    public void OnConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result)
    {
        App.PostLoginAction(SocialProvider.Google, null, $"An error occurred: {result.ErrorMessage}");
    }
}
```