# Xamarin Forms Android GoogleSignIn How to Refresh/reload Token?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-signin

So, I have this code which works fine:

```cs
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.GetLastSignedInAccount(currentActivity);
```

I get back an `account`. The `IsExpired` property is true on the account.

This causes downstream problems because it doesn't force the sign in intent to run I guess.

**How can I refresh the token on Xamarin Forms Android?** I have found some examples of this for the javascript client or other languages but I can't seem to find out where you reload the token in Xamarin land.

Comment: here is a old question you may want to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553846/xamarin-google-signin-for-android-refresh-and-access-tokens

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was looking for something that was the equivalent of `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().reloadAuthResponse()`, my guess is that is sort of what `SilentSignInAsync()` does? The documentation always seems to be a choose your own adventure with google.